# Scope (root node, context) of XSLT "key" Element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, msxsl

I have an XSLT key defined. I need to access the key from within a for-each loop, where that loop is processing a node-set that is outside the scope of where the key was defined.

Snippet, where I've marked two lines, one which works and one which does not:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('name', 'use')"/> <!-- works -->
<xsl:for-each select="$outOfScopeNodeSet">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('name', 'use')"/> <!-- does not work -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there a way to access the key from within the for-each loop?

XSLT 1.0, msxsl engine.

(I could not think of a reasonable way to provide a full working example for this. I'm also not sure of the correct terminology, such as "scope" - perhaps if I knew the correct terminology I'd be able to find my answer already. If the question is not clear enough please let me know and I'll try to edit it into better shape.)

Comment: Try reducing this to the smallest example that is a complete, valid XSLT, and provide an XML file to match, showing the expected output.

Comment: Hi Jim. I was not able to do this yesterday, but after Michael's answer below I now understand the problem and would be able to do it. The $outOfScopeNodeSet indeed had a root which was not the same as that of the document being processed, due to the use of msxsl:node-set() buried deep withing hundreds of lines of XSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, keys do not work across documents. It seems that your `$outOfScopeNodeSet` contains a node-set whose root node is different from the root node of the XML document being processed (probably created by the `exsl:node-set()` function?) - while the key is supposed to fetch a value from the processed XML document.

To resolve this problem, you need to return the context back to the processed XML document before calling the `key()` function, for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />
<xsl:for-each select="$outOfScopeNodeSet">
    <xsl:variable name="use" select="some-value" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$root">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('name', $use)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Hi Michael. The $outOfScopeNodeSet indeed had a root which was not the same as that of the document being processed, due to the use of msxsl:node-set() buried deep withing hundreds of lines of XSL. Thanks for your explanation and for the suggested solution.